# Create multidimensional array of all possible triplets

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I have an array that contains a list of crypto symbols, eg. (as there is over a thousand)

```
symbols = ['agve', 'age', 'ageur', 'agfi']
```

And I need to create a multidimensional array that contains all possible combinations of these, eg.

```
combinations = [
                 ["agve", "age", "ageur"],
                 ["agve", "age", "agfi"],
                 ["age", "ageur", "agfi"],
               ...
```

The resulting array should not have duplicate permutations such as `["agve", "age", "ageur"]`, `["agve", "ageur", "age"]`

I honestly don't even know where to start with this. The closest I can get is to build an
array with some of the pairs (and then, not written, the goal was to gradually search and add missing combinations):

```
    array_length = len(symbols)
    combinations = []
    current      = 0
    for i in range(array_length-3):
        combinations.append([symbols[current], symbols[current+1], symbols[current+2]])
        current += 1
```

Any help would be much appreciated. The rest of my project is written in Python 3.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lot of memory to take up, can you consider each triplet one at a time? Either way, the easiest method is probably itertools.combinations.

```
from itertools import combinations

# Consider each individually
for triplet in combinations(symbols, 3):
    #DO SOMETHING
    pass

# Create the multidimentional array as you wanted
triplets = list(combinations(symbols, 3))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And thank you for suggesting to handle the triplets individually, that should actually suit my situation quite well. My concern was running into an infinite loop. I have the first test running now but it's looking promising.